# Does async http download finish when ViewController is popped?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

it seems like an easy question to me but I can't find an answer anywhere.

I have a view controller that downloads data asynchronously and then saves it, when a button is pressed.

Can I be sure that the asynchronous request will finish (the ViewController is the delegate) and the data will be saved even when the ViewController has been popped? Otherwise I would check whether the download has been finished when it is popped and if not start a background thread to download the data.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How are you doing the download?  NSURLConnection?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should be do all of your data downloading in a model class, rather than a controller (MVC).

Create a singleton NSObject that contains all of your logic for downloading from the web, and stores it within the singleton. That way any class in your app can access that data and you don't have to worry about viewControllers being dealloc'ed when you pop it from the Navigation Stack.

Singleton example:

```
+ (YourObject *)object
{
    static YourObject *_object = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        _object = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return _object;
}
```

Comment: How do I tell the ViewController, that the data has been loaded? Do I set the ViewController as the singleton's delegate? The ViewController first shows a low quality image and in the background loads a higher resolution version. So how do I know when this image is available?

Comment: @ProgrammingBonn You could create a block callback for the singleton. So in your ViewController that tells the singleton to make the API call, you could pass it a block (or a delegate if that's more your thing) that will run on completion, or will call the delegate to notify. You could also use NSNotifications to broadcast changes from your singleton to the entire app

Comment: Sorry to bother with one more question. Once I downloaded the image in the singleton, do I save it to the singleton or do I only add it to the ImageView and then forget about it. First seems more logical but the second option seems more performant. Appreciate your help!

Comment: This to me would depend on the situation. Are you only using this image in one location in your app or is it something that would be nice for the rest of your app to have access to? Will you need to download this image every time that view is displayed? If so caching the image would be a good idea so that you don't have to keep downloading it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you separate asynch request from uiviewcontroller.

Otherwise please be sure that every action on UI will be triggered on main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 

    //implement your code on UI

});
```

if uiviewcontroller has connected delegate and controller still exists (not nil) then method comes from delegate will run even if uiview controller doesn't appear yet.

Cheers